# Bootstrap help two forms

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Please help me to understand if I did correct the code for this image. I didn't finished because I wasn't sure that is right.

[Two forms for bootstrap image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaJRP.jpg)

Boostrap:

```
<div class="home-top-selects container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="consulter-form col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
            <h2>Consulter les petites annonces</h2>
            <div class="form-group container">
               <h4>Par mot-cle les petites annonces<h4>
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option>Toutes categories</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="button-and-input">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="consulter-form col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <h2>Trouver une entreprise</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough code for anyone to answer your question - which is a question you should be able to answer yourself by just comparing the two visually.

Comment: I'm don't know very well bootstrap that's why I asked other people to help me. Even what I wrote I'm not sure if is good or not :).

Comment: Ah, I see. You're on the right path, but you should familiarize yourself with bootstrap's grid system. Have a look at their documentation: [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: I followed that website to write that code. At least please tell me where did u see a mistake :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is incorrect.

Try something like:

```
<div class="home-top-selects container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="consulter-form col-sm-6">
            <h2>Consulter les petites annonces</h2>
            <form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4>Par mot-cle les petites annonces</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option>Toutes categories</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <h4>Oú?</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <select class="form-control" id="select-flags">
                            <option>France</option>
                            <option>Spain</option>
                            <option>Brazil</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <select class="form-control" id="another-select">
                            <option>toutes les villes select</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                            Lancez Votre Recherche
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <h5 class="text-info text-center">
                    Faite une recherche dans votre périmètre grâce à votre géolocalisation.
                </h4>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2>Trouver Une Enterprise</h2>
            <form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h4>Par mot-clé ou nom d'enterprise</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <h4>Oú?</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr-2" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <select class="form-control" id="another-select-2">
                            <option>toutes les villes select</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <select class="form-control" id="select-flags-2">
                            <option>France</option>
                            <option>Spain</option>
                            <option>Brazil</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Place this to fill the blank space -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h4>&#160;</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="different-select">
                            <option>Autres options de recherche</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                            Chercher
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr/>

                <div class="text-center">
                    <h2 class="text-info">
                        Votre enterprise n'est pas référencée?
                    </h2>
                    <button class="btn btn-large btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> AJOUTER MON ENTERPRISE 
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some comments about:

- <s>Consider providing a fiddle to your code.</s> The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ricardovigatti/wo11dtvs/
- col-sm-* are for small viewports, but medium and large viewports will understand it and use it anyway.
- <s>You don't provide any form tag. You will need two of</s>.
- <s>I did not test my code, we can improve it if you decide to use.</s>
- You were at the right path, but remember that trying by yourself is always the best for learning...

Comment: looks correct so far my friend. You are a master. If you can add a little one from the right to understand better the forms you be a superstar :).

Comment: @JohnSmith, i edited my answer. I've added the second form with some improvments at the first one... I think the semantic of bootstrap and html are great now. I also provided a fiddle, it's better to understand...

Comment: Thank you very much Ricardo. Beside the simple examples from bootstrap site, I learned how complex forms work.

Comment: form are always complex to build, with raw css, bootstrap or any other framework. xD